# Is it safe / okay to show Google Adsense only to visitors from Search Engines?

Tags: google, search-engines, google-adsense

There are a lot of code example out there that helps users do this. Eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693729/how-to-display-google-adsense-ads-to-search-engine-traffic-only

But I was looking authoritative links or answers, since there is no answer in Adsense TOS.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any reason that it wouldn't be OK with AdSense.

The only issue you might have is from the organic search side.  If you are showing any kind of content only to search users (including ads) that could be considered "[cloaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking)".  To ensure that you don't get an organic ranking penalty, you would want to make sure you serve the same page to search engine robots (like Googlebot) that you serve to visitors from search engines.

Comment: I concur to some extend. You could be using the language defined by the browser to choose what to show to the user (i.e. French or English?) and that should not be considered cloaking. One way to avoid that connotation is to use a proper canonical so the search engines can see the "ultimate" page (in case of the language, it could be to force the language with ?lang=en at the end of the path.)

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the contributors on the AdSense forums to be authoritative, then they don't seem to find any problems with selecting what visitors to show Google ads to.

https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/caLd7wnkTW4/kCGsvS_aLIAJ

https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/JNPb6d4ShTU/VNtX5v_BbPcJ

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe.

Reason : Nowhere it is mentioned that it is unsafe. [Giants like twitter do that](http://sugarrae.com/online-marketing/social-media/is-twitter-cloaking-their-site-to-show-adsense-ads-in-their-cache/). 
The only risk associated with cloaking is SEO issues, as [cloaking is against the Google webmaster Guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en).